# SQL Server - delete duplicate rows of a table that has many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have in SQL Server a table that has many-to-many relatioships with another tables.
So, my situation is:
`Table A` has columns (for example `[ID_A], name, surname, ...`)
`Table B` has columns (for example `[ID_B], field1, field2, field3, ...`)
`Table AB` is the relation table between `Table A` and `Table B` which has only 2 columns (ID_A, ID_B). The `delete rule` and `update rule` are `ON CASCADE` (the properties update/delete between `Table A` and `Table AB` is `ON CASCADE`; the properties update/delete between `Table AB` and `Table B` is `ON CASCADE`).

But in `Table A` I have some duplicate rows:

```
ID_A   Name   Surname
--------------------
1      Alice  Brown
2      Bob    White
3      Alice  Brown
4      Alice  Brown
5      Alice  Brown
6      Bob    White
```

and every row has in relationship with `Table B` row. I want this situation in Table A:

```
 ID_A   Name   Surname
 ---------------------
 1     Alice  Brown
 2     Bob    White
```

so I want to remove the duplicate row and its relationship with `Table B` row. `Table B` has not numeric IDs.

Don't worry about the data, I just want one row, for example one row for Alice Brown, one row for Bob White, and so on. These tables are examples! (I know that two people can have same name and surname :) )

I can find duplicate rows using:

```
SELECT
    field
FROM
    Table
GROUP BY
    field
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

But I don't know how to join the `DELETE` statement with `DUPLICATE SEARCH` statement. I've just tried to manually delete records in `Table A`, but the cascade did not work.

Can someone help me?
Thank you

Comment: Did you try DELETE TOP(1) FROM ...

Comment: As part of the solution, seems you should also be added a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` or `UNIQUE INDEX` to your table so that you can't end up with duplicates in the future; otherwise you'll be forever chasing your tail.

Comment: @Bart one row can have many duplicates, not only one. These tables are examples.

Comment: @Larnu thanks but now I must resolve this situation. The DB was not created by me.

Comment: @rlnnclt if you should do this once , you can get distinct of data to the new table via insert select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe delete the duplicate rows first, like this:

```
DELETE 
A 
FROM TABLEA A
     INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT *, 
               RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY name, surname                               
               ORDER BY ID_A) rank
        FROM TABLEA 
    ) T ON A.ID_A = t.ID_A
    WHERE rank > 1;
```

And then delete rows in your matrix table that no longer exist in Table A.

```
DELETE FROM TABLEB WHERE ID_A NOT IN(SELECT ID_A FROM TABLEA)
```

(Note the delete statement may be off syntax-wise as I am typing from phone!)

Comment: Hi, don't worry :)

 But even I've set the rules delete and update CASCADE, I have this error:

Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_TableAB_TableA". The conflict occurred in database "My DB", table "dbo.TableAB", column 'ID_A'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Can you disable constraints momentarily?

Comment: nope. I Can't. Table B has not numeric IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a subquery:

```
delete from Table where ID_A in (
  -- use min or max 
  select max(ID_A) from Table
  group by Name, Surname
  having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. But How can I join this to a delete statement? Tables are in many-tom-many relationships.

Comment: I updated the query